# SQL Recordset close inside loop

Tags: sql, vba

I have a question regarding opening and closing an recordset inside my loop. 
The code that I now have works fine, except for the fact that I know it can be coded in an different, much faster or nicer way. I am not that advanced with SQL, therefore my question.

due to the fact I have to close my recordset everytime the code is a bit slow.

```
 Do Until Cells(c, 2).Value = Empty
        TeamMember = Cells(c, 2).Value

        r = 4
        For i = 4 To 34
            Days = Cells(r, i).Value

             strSQL = "SELECT [" & TeamMember & "] From [Planning$] Where [Days]=" & "#" & Format(Days, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#" & ""
             rs.Open strSQL, DBConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
             Cells(c, i).Offset(0, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
             rs.Close
            Next i
        c = c + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: The only way to do it more efficiently would be to say `where [days] in ("` and then concatenate rows 4 to 34, so `"#" & join(application.transpose(range("a4:a34").Value) ,"#,#") & "#"` would give you this.   However, it looks like you're looking for the corresponding result to the date.  I'd take the lot between the min and max dates, and then look this up from another sheet. Another thing is, if you get more than one result in your recordset, you'll over write them as `c` only increases by 1.

Comment: Or, open the recordset from min(row 4 to 34) to max(row 4 to 34) and then use methods of the recordset object, like `.find` for your dates, then you just need to `rst.movefirst` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using something like this

```
"Where [Days]>=#" & _
                CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("a4:a34"))) & _
                "# AND [Days]<=#" & _
                CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("a4:a34"))) & "#"
```

Then use the recordset `.find` method to look for your date, then just use `.moveFirst` each loop.

Comment: thanks Nathan, just tried it. managed to speed it up a bit. with your adjustment to the code I now paste and transpose the results.